# Python 2- using variable in place of number to get letter in string

Tags: python

I looked for the solution to my solution, but either couldn't find it or didn't understand it when I did. I'm fairly new to coding. I am making a pig-latin translator with an extra feature, it can translate FROM pig-latin. My translate TO works perfectly, but when translating FROM I get an error called "IndexError: string index out of range" on line 19, the place where "end = word[length]" is. Now, I need to know if using variables to replace integers in Python just doesn't work, or if it's a problem somewhere else in my code. (Please note that I do have a bit of code in there to MAKE SURE my variable is a integer.)

```
print "Welcome to pig-latin translater!"
word = raw_input("What word do you want to translate?")
continue1 = False
while continue1 == False:
    tofrom = str(raw_input("Do you want to translate to or from pig-latin?"))
    tofrom = tofrom.lower()
    if tofrom == "to":
        length = len(word)
        start = word[0]
        end = word[1:length]
        translation = end + start
        word = str.title(word)
        translation = translation.lower()
        print "%s in pig-latin is %s." % (word, translation)
        continue1 = True
    elif tofrom == "from":
        length = len(word)
        length = int(length)
        end = word[length]
        length = length - 1
        start = word[0:length]
        translation = end + start
        word = str.title(word)
        translation = translation.lower()
        print "%s is %s in English." % (word, translation)
        continue1 = True
    else:
        print "Please answer to or from."
end = raw_input("Press enter to exit.")
```

Comment: inspire us with your code snippet

Comment: It's a problem with your code.  The error means "you're trying to access an index beyond the end of the string".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand much of your question. But I believe you forgot that iterating over a list is starting from 0.
So if you want to access last position of string you should subtract 1 from it's length.

```
word = "ABC def"
length = len(word)  # 7
end = word[length - 1]  # because there is no 7th element, only 0123456
```

---

You can improve things over here:

```
    length = len(word)
    length = int(length)  # len() already returns int, no need to convert this again
    end = word[length]  # here is the issue I have provided answer abowe
    length = length - 1  # this line should be above aboves line
```

---

Also, you don't need to know the lenght of the string. You can use an expression like this:

```
end = word[1:]  # means from 1st element to the end
```

Comment: Sorry for not posting my code earlier. I remembered.  (Although I didn't see it at first, and when tested with 'elloh" it came out with "hell". Either a funny mistake or my computer hates me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my invalid syntax. (And the int(length) was only a leftover test I did earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

It's time to learn a few basics in indexing a Python sequence.

First, as the earlier answer also points out, sequences begin with index 0; the final element is at index len-1.

You can also index from the other end with negative numbers: the last element is -1, the penultimate is -2, and so on.

When you're taking a slice, you can omit a starting index of 0 or ending index of -1.

I assume that you realize this doesn't work ... yet.  Moving a single character is not the proper transformation for pig Latin.  However, this is an good example of incremental programming: do one or two small additions at a time, test those, and then continue.  I suggest that you next work on your outer flow control: make this loop *ad lib*, so you can test multiple inputs without restarting the program for every word.

```
elif tofrom == "from":
    end = word[-1]
    start = word[:-1]
    translation = end + start
    word = str.title(word)
    translation = translation.lower()
    print "%s is %s in English." % (word, translation)
    continue1 = True
```